# Javascript - sorting an array of 2-parameter objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, sql-order-by

Consider the following array:

```
var thingsThatMatter = [
    {"Colour of hair", "High"}, 
    {"Colour of eyes", "Low"}, 
    {"Colour of shoes", "Medium"}
];
```

Apologies for the example, but the key part here is the high, medium, low parameter.
That's the data I'm working with (1,2,3 would of been much easier...!)

Is there anyway I can easily sort the array, so that the items run in order - High, Medium, Low?

Or, is there a way I can "get" the item that has the value "Low" as a priority parameter?

*Note- the structure of this will be changed to numerical later, however for now, this is what I have to work with.*

Comment: Do you mean high, medium, and low will be numbers and you need to sort the structure based on that?

Comment: That's not syntactically valid JS, btw. Did you mean for the elements to be arrays, or objects?

Comment: Have a look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+sort+array+of+objects+by+property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array.sort()` with a custom compare function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

---

Here, have a cookie:

```
var thingsThatMatter = [
    ["Colour of hair", "High"],
    ["Colour of eyes", "Low"],
    ["Colour of shoes", "Medium"]
];

function comparator(a, b) {
    a = comparator.priorities[a[1]];
    b = comparator.priorities[b[1]];

    if (a > b) return 1;
    if (a < b) return -1;
    return 0;
}

comparator.priorities = {
    High: 0,
    Medium: 1,
    Low: 2
}

thingsThatMatter.sort(comparator);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/T3hNm/

Comment: I'll place a side-bet that the OP meant for the array to contain objects not arrays. (That is, his typo was `,` for `:`, not `{` for `[`. We'll see...